# Issue uploading file with CURL, PHP and Apache on Windows

Tags: php, curl

I'm having issues uploading files using CURL with PHP (on Windows - if it matters).

Basically, I can post to the URL and display what has been posted except for the field with the file. In this case, I'm testing code that points to the same server, but once I can confirm that the file gets uploaded, I will send to another domain (again, if it matters).

Here is start.php

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pass");
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL, "http://domain/upload.php");
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$post = array("boo"=>"yaaah",
        "xml"=>"@e:/path/to/file/new.xml");
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

Then, upload.php

```
print_r($_POST);
```

The result of the CURL call, the output of $buffer:

```
array(1) { ["boo"]=> string(5) "yaaah" }
```

**Edit #1**

Instead, I did an print_r($_FILES) and got this:

```
array(1) { ["xml"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(7) "new.xml" ["type"]=> string(24) "application/octet-stream" ["tmp_name"]=> string(26) "C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\php892.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(3733) } }
```

This proves that my file is being uploaded. Why it isn't being picked up by the API I'm trying to access is a question for them to answer :)

Comment: What happens or doesn't happen? What is `curl_error()` saying?

Comment: @Pekka No error. Getting HTTP code 202. I wasn't using the proper scope when looking for my files. Things are good now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get information about uploaded files,

```
print_r($_POST);
```

is not helpful. You might want to look into [`$_FILES`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) as well:

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

That is the variable that contains information about the file uploads. Please [read the manual about uploading files](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. It provided me with the confirmation that the file is indeed going through.